# Unable to boot phone after deleting folders in SD storage

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

Am using a Samsung galaxy duos. I recently deleted everything from my sd card/usb storage and when I restarted my phone, it just keeps displaying the Samsung start screen but it doesn't boot up.
please help,need advice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try booting it into recovery mode.

To enter recovery mode turn the device off and hold VOL UP, VOL DOWN, HOME and POWER. When the phone vibrates let go of the buttons and it should boot into recovery mode.

Now using the volume keys to move up and down the list and the power button to select, go to wipe data/factory reset. Select yes. Wait for it to reset. Now select reboot system now.

If you still get stuck on the splash screen you will probably have to re-flash the firmware using ODIN. There are plenty of guides on YouTube and XDA for using ODIN to re-flash firmware, just watch any tutorial but use the firmware for your device, which you can get here http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/. Simply search for your device (S7562) and download the firmware for your country.

I would tell you how to use ODIN but I haven't used it for quite a while but it is pretty simple, all you really do is press a button, good luck.